# When to call function with and without parenthesis brackets ()?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working through a tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/Q7AOvWpIVHU?t=838) and have encountered some syntax that I don't fully understand.

I want it to be that every time I scroll, console.log logs "hello".

```js
function moveCamera() {
  console.log("hello");
}

document.body.onscroll = moveCamera()
```

```js
function moveCamera() {
  console.log("hello");
}

document.body.onscroll = moveCamera
```

In the first example, console.log("hello") runs once, but then never again, regardless of my scrolling.

In the second example, the code runs and logs "hello" every time there is a scroll.

I understand that for the second example, moveCamera passes a copy of the function, making a function that looks somewhat like this:

```
document.body.onscroll = function () {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

However, I still don't understand why calling moveCamera() with parenthesis **doesn't** work and yields **undesired functionality.**

EDIT: I devised a pretty easy way to understand when to use parenthesis and when not to. I'll put it here since my question was labelled duplicate.

**Without Parenthesis Examples**

```js
// Example 1: If you are assigning, use reference
document.body.onscroll = moveCamera;
// Example 2: If you are event listening, use reference
document.body.addEventListener("scroll", moveCamera);
```

**With Parenthesis Examples**

```js
// Example 1: If you are executing on a single line alone, use call.
...
moveCamera()
...
// Example 2: If you want to repeatedly call this function, 
// like I did in my example, use a loop or an animate() function.
// @note this is a THREE.js specific example
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  moveCamera()
  renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
```

Comment: `onscroll` expects a function not whatever the function returns. Functions in JS are objects that can be assigned and passed around just like arrays for example. This is called first-class functions.

Comment: @gunt.r to help visualise it, imagine if your first example was instead two lines: `var itsReturnValue = moveCamera();` and then `document.body.onscroll = itsReturnValue;`. As `moveCamera()` does not return anything at all, `onscroll` ends up with the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a string with the function. Not the function itself because it would return whatever the function return. Also, I recommend to use the `setAttribute()` function:

```
document.body.setAttribute("onscroll", "moveCamera()");
```

---

- Supposed you have this function, using `moveCamera()` without quotation marks:

```js
function moveCamera() {
  return "console.log('Hello')";
}

document.body.setAttribute("onscroll", moveCamera());
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

- Using `moveCamera()` with quotation marks as a string:

```js
function moveCamera() {
  console.log("Hello");
}

document.body.setAttribute("onscroll", "moveCamera()");
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: I tired it and it didn't work. It just assigned a string.

Comment: Look at my updated answer, maybe now you could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke `moveCamera` you are assigning the value returned by the `moveCamera` function rather than the function itself.

This is illustrated in the following example:

```js
function a(){
  return "b";
}
var a = a;
var b = a();

console.log("a = "+a);
console.log("b = "+b);
```